# Переопределение абстрактного метода возвращающего пользовательский тип

Tags: c#

Что-то я совсем запутался и/или торможу, но решить данную проблему никак не могу. Есть абстрактный класс с абстрактным методом, возврашающим некий новый класс:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract B foo();
}
public abstract class B
{
    protected int x;
}
```

Есть производный класс А1 от А. Так же есть некий класс С, от которого уже является производным B1.

```
public class A1 : A
{
    public override B1 foo()
    {
        ...
        ...
        return B1; //Ошибка - нельзя неявно преобразовать B1 в B
    }
}
public class B1 : C, B //Последнее как в С в С# нельзя
{
    private int y;
}
public class С
{
    private int z;
}
```

Как мне правильно переопределить foo и определить B1, чтобы в итоге все работало, а возвращамый foo объект содержал аттрибуты x, y и z. От множетсвенного наследования в C# отказались. Пробовал писать интерфейс для B и дополнительно от него наследовать B1, но все равно ошибка неявного преобразования...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C# нет множественного наследования для классов. Но есть для интерфейсов. А ещё есть обобщенные типы. Например, 3 интерфейса

```
public interface A
{
    int X { get;}
}

public interface B 
{
    int Y { get; }
}

public interface C 
{
    int Z { get; }
}
```

Абстрактный создатель

```
public abstract class Creator<T> 
{
    public abstract T Create();
}
```

Что будем создавать

```
public class ABC : A, B, C
{
    public int X {get;set;}
    public int Y {get;set;}
    public int Z {get;set;}
}
```

Реализация создателя

```
public class ConcreteCreator : Creator<ABC>
{
    public override ABC Create()
    {
        return new ABC() { X = 10, Y = 20, Z = 30 };
    }
}
```

Как всё это юзать

```
var creator = new ConcreteCreator();
var obj = creator.Create();

Console.WriteLine(obj.X);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Y);
Console.WriteLine(obj.Z);
```

Вывод

```
10
20
30
```

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ! Ваш вариант мне не совсем подойдет, так как внутри A в моем примере будет много функций, которые обязаны быть переопределены, но возвращать они будут объекты разных классов. Да и не хочется столько криэйтеров создавать. Но вопрос решился пустого написанием интерфейса для B и наследованием его в B1. Я решил отказаться от каких-либо аттрибутов в B, так как они будут совершенно разные в B1 и других проивзодных от B. Тут в тонкости надо вдаватся, а пример написал специально упрощенный. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @AlexeyTrushin имейте ввиду, что, возможно, задача, которую вы решаете, уже где  то решена другим способом. Я бы на вашем месте внимательно поглядел бы не на то, как запрограмировать классы, а на саму композицию классов - верный ли выбрали путь решения.

Comment: Согласен. Собственно сейчас и приходится перерабатывать то, что в свое время было на коленке запрогано... По сути хочу сделать один базовый класс со стандартными атрибутами и методами, от которого будут наследоваться производные классы для работы с АПИ разных криптобирж. И задача этого базового класса по сути быть только подсказкой (а точнее стопером), что пока все методы не реализуешь, компилироваться не будет = АПИ не работает и его использовать еще нельзя. А в самом приложении уже использовать эти универсальные методы